# HTML forms: focus on checkbox after completing text field

Tags: html, forms, user-experience

Look at this HTML form and notice how it has a checkbox between text fields:

[image: screenshot1]

I tried to fill it up with Chrome on mobile and noticed an unexpected problem: if the user types into a text field, and then moves to the next field by pressing the blue "done" button in an Android keyboard, focus will jump over the checkbox into the next text field. This would be fine, except for the fact that **the user never even sees the checkbox** and thus may leave it unintentionally unchecked:

[image: screenshot2]

Is it possible to force focus on the checkbox field or something like that? If there is no technical solution, I'll be happy to accept a UX solution.

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input name="text1" value="Some text"><br>
  <input name="text2" value="More text"><br>
  <input name="text3" value="Bla bla"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input name="text1" value="Some text"><br>
  <input name="text2" value="More text"><br>
  <input name="text3" value="Bla bla"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `change` Event & `.focus()`

Try registering a `change` event on `[name=text3]` and trigger a `.focus()` on `[name=vehicle]`. When user has typed into `[name=text3]` then clicks elsewhere, a `.focus()` is triggered on `[name=vehicle]`

### Demo

```js
var blaBla = document.querySelector('[name=text3]');

var bike = document.querySelector('[name=vehicle]');

blaBla.addEventListener('change', goToChk);

function goToChk(e) {
  bike.focus();
}
```

```css
[name=vehicle]:focus {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input name="text1" value="Some text"><br>
  <input name="text2" value="More text"><br>
  <input name="text3" value="Bla bla"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input name="text1" value="Some text"><br>
  <input name="text2" value="More text"><br>
  <input name="text3" value="Bla bla"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hmmh, this seems to work in a toy example, but I can't get it to work in the actual HTML file. And I'm not sure what exactly is breaking it there, so I'm finding it hard to produce another MVCE.

Comment: Do have a link? I could take a look. Nevermind I got.

Comment: The reason why is because it's actually a label associated with a checkbox that's hidden.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.form-input-checkbox').focus();`

Comment: @AtteJuvonen I can't test it with that crazy alert, can you get rid of it please.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. The alert has been gone for awhile (hard refresh the page if you still see it). I just tested this and it is able to select the element, but calling focus() on it does nothing.

Comment: I think there's a way to do it by making the checkbox present but invisible and place it inside the label. You'll probably have to adjust the CSS...