# JS: prevent text input field from gaining focus unless clicked

Tags: javascript, html

When I use Chrome on Android to fill a web form, by pressing the blue "enter" button the browser auto focuses on the next text field. How can I prevent this from happening?

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input name="text1" value="Bla bla"><br>
  <input name="text2" value="Some text"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

If anyone is curious why I need this, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175698/html-forms-focus-on-checkbox-after-completing-text-field/54176093) (the answer to that question does not solve my actual problem even though it solved the toy version of it).

Comment: Try to set `tabindex="-1"` for the inputs.

Comment: For mobile web, it's actually quite important to let the form to get focus, in order to bring the keyboard out, to hint user to enter information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply**

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input name="text1" value="Bla bla" tabindex="-1"><br>
  <input name="text2" value="Some text" tabindex="-1"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The issue with this is ,If he has 20 inputs then he'll have to go and add this to 20 of them

Comment: @ThanveerShah he asked for the solution given only 2 inputs in the question

Comment: yeah I know, I just said a scenario that's all

Comment: This is terrible for accessibility concerns because `tabindex="-1"` makes the element unreachable for users who rely on keyboard navigation (blind, motor disabilities)

Answer (score 1):

To disable autofocus on all input elements use this.

```
$(function(){
        $('input').blur();
    });
```

To disable autofocus on a particular element, pass the element id as below:

```
$(function(){
    $('input#someid').blur();
});
```

OR you can use this

```
$('input').each(function() {               
    $(this).attr('tabindex', '-1');
});
```

Comment: this will not work where JS is disabled in browser