# HTML form: disable enter keypress without side-effects

Tags: javascript, html, forms, user-experience

I have [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175698/html-forms-focus-on-checkbox-after-completing-text-field) with mobile browsers auto focusing on form fields when the user presses enter. I want to disable this "auto focus on enter" behavior. I have a solution, but the solution disables tabbing between fields. Is there a better solution?

Here is a simple form where you can demonstrate auto focus:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
    <input name="text1" value="Bla bla"><br>
    <input name="text2" value="Some text"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my attempt to fix the problem ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jc2bwp6s/2/)):

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" onkeypress="return handleEnter(event.keyCode);">
    <input name="text1" value="Bla bla"><br>
    <input name="text2" value="Some text"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

window.handleEnter = function(keyCode) {
     if (keyCode == 13) {
         $(':focus').blur(); // intent: to stop auto focus
         return false; // intent: prevent submit
     }
     return true;
}
```

After trying this on mobile, it looks like pressing enter (the big blue button on Android keyboard) actually behaves like a tab until our focus is at the last focusable form element, at which point it behaves like an enter. If we add `tabindex="-1"` to each input field, we can prevent auto focus on mobile, but then we also prevent tabbing on desktop. And I suppose we could hack together something that changes tabIndex for mobile only, but umm, ugh.

So my question is can I disable "auto focus on enter" behavior on mobile... in a nice way?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want autofocus? Since this behaviour is the UX people would expect on mobile. You could write a CSS stylesheet with a mobile only rule to set the tab-index to -1 ( for example, if the screen is smaller than x/y ) .

Comment: @Shilly check the first link in OP. It explains the problem with screenshots.

Comment: Wouldn't it be preferred to actually put a tab-index on the checkboxes as well so tabbing shows them? Or change the styling so that they stand out more? Or just add `required` to the checkbox so you can't actually submit the form without checking the checkbox?

Comment: Yes it would be preferrable to tab to the checkboxes as well. I just can't get it to work (somehow the custom styling of checkboxes prevents being able to focus on them). The checkbox is optional, I want people to see it and then decide if they want to accept it or not.

Comment: Any way you could post the checkbox and its styling? I remember having issues with making certain elements focusable if they were inline and such. If making the checkbox tabbable fixes all issues, it's a way better solution that breaking expected behaviour.

Comment: It's basically due to the design. Instead of using an actual checkbox, you use a display:none checkbox and styled a span to resemble a checkbox. Hence the tabbing can never work. Is this part of a framework? Else the solution is just to use the actual checkbox and style it as the span is styled right now instead. The alternative is to make the span tabbable, which it'll never be by default, but that'll be more work.

Comment: Hmmh ok. The problem also repeats with the buttons, which appear to be tabbable in desktop but not tabbable in mobile. Because of this I started now googling for how to make the span tabbable.

Comment: Did you write the span? Or is it part of bootstrap? Basically you'll need to change the display and add a tabindex. But then you also need a onfocus event listener to actually focus the checkbox. Hence it'd be way easier if you can just use an actual checkbox instead of faking one.

Comment: It's not part of bootstrap. I wrote it mimicking some examples I found by googling. It took me about 6 hours just to get the checkbox working as it is now, so I don't think I will start that process again from scratch :/ If there isn't any easy solution maybe I'll just disable tabbing altogether then.

Comment: `<div><input class="checkmark" name="whatsapp1" type="checkbox" id="whatsapp1"><label for="whatsapp1">Saa liittää hääpäivänä WhatsApp-ryhmään</label></div>` does not work I guess? You kinda caused your own problem I fear by mimicing a checkbox. Keep in mind that the CSS rule you use for the checkbox `input[type="checkbox"]` will be global, so your solution will disable all your checkboxes instead of only this forms one, so you might have to change it later on anyway.

Comment: I tried that now and it breaks both alignment and ability to tick the box. I imagine maybe with another 6 hours I could rebuild the checkbox like that, but it just doesn't seem worth the effort. Thanks for your help in any case.

Comment: Since I see you aligning stuff with <br> and such, have a look at the CSS grid system to make aligning items easy. It'll allow you to remove a bunch of the useless div wrappers that are just there to align things and that make everything way more difficult to work with than needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try to do it cleaner next time I need a website. This site is pretty much done at this point though.